# Is MySQL appropriate for this?

Tags: mysql

I need to store 'blocks' of data that would be thousands of lines x maybe 30 number each line.

My concept is to store each of these blocks in a cell. A table might contain 50 columns and maybe 20 rows. So that's maybe 1000 blocks of this huge data per table.

Would the MySQL limits allow this?

If not, can you suggest a different way to organize this data - or another database perhaps?

Comment: What is the data for, how would it be queried and what is the rationale behind storing it this way?

Comment: Each line of each block of data consists of a date , and number. The blocks aw equity curves for unique variable settings for a financial trading system.

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the [`TEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html) datatypes to store these blocks. These columns can be very large, but the data is stored in separate files, and doesn't count towards MySQL's limits on the size of table rows.

From the documentation on [limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html):

> `BLOB` and `TEXT` columns count from one to four plus eight bytes each toward the row-size limit because their contents are stored separately from the rest of the row.

Comment: Thank you. I did a quick search and did you mean to store as VARCHAR? because it appears that there is a limit with VARCHAR:

Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used. See Section C.10.4, “Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size”.

Comment: My point is that `VARCHAR` has a limit, `TEXT` doesn't (well, the limit is very large, similar to the limit on file sizes). I linked to the documentation, you shouldn't need to search.

Comment: I added the documentation that supports my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best thing you could do would be saving that block of data in a file and store only the file name, date, ids and etc in your MySQL database. Unless you have to crawl those block of data with complicated Mysql queries, this is the better way imo

Comment: This is essentially how the `BLOB` and `TEXT` datatypes work in MySQL, but the server manages the files automatically for you.